# tslint:disable not working in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

Can not import type declaration files. Consider importing "googlemaps" instead of "@ types / googlemaps".

[image]

I have the default options but this does not work for me.

Comment: Are you sure this is a `tslint` error message and no `ts` message? (When you hover over it)

Comment: The file '@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts' is not a module. the errors are from ts

Comment: Then you need to fix this error. `tslint:disable` will only disable tslint related errors **not** actual `ts` errors.

Answer (score 3):

In addition of not being related to the linter, as commented, [issue 16472](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16472#issuecomment-311524892) adds:

> In the vast majority of cases, an import from a module specifier beginning with `@types` is a bug and will result in a runtime error.

See for instance [tinganho/express-request-language PR 13](https://github.com/tinganho/express-request-language/pull/13):

> With the newer version of TypeScript => 2.4.1 there is the pointed error.
>   Importing types directly is an error, instead packages from which types are used should be imported.

```
-import * as e from '@types/express';
+import * as e from 'express';
```

See also "[Deprecation Notice: Regarding TypeScript@2.0](https://github.com/typings/typings#deprecation-notice-regarding-typescript20)".